# git push working perfectly but git pull isn`t

Tags: git, github, push

`git pull` stopped working. I was working on an additional branch and push it to a github private repo but when I tried to pull the changes it said:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/username/repo.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

I tried changing to ssh but the same error appeared but on port 22

Doing some more tries I discovered that in my branch feature I could do push and pull but not in develop or master, not even any new branch

Comment: What is the upstream on feature and what isthe upstream on develop?

Comment: I notice you're using HTTP, have you tried adjusting the url to use HTTPS?

Comment: This sort of thing is usually a network configuration issue. Make sure you can connect to GitHub via http, https, and/or ssh when *not* using Git; then Git should be able to connect the same way.

Answer (score 0):

(note : this is more a formatted comment, asking for more details, than an answer)

- Are you able to clone again the repository from the same url ?

In a suitable directory, run :

```
# clone it in a folder that you will delete afterwards :
git clone [url] repo.tmp
```

(just checking : your repo does show up in a web browser, right ?)

- Do you have one single remote ? are `push` and `pull` urls the same ?

To check that, run :

```
git remote -v
```

- Are your branches set up with remote branches located in the same remote ?

You can view that using :

```
# remote branches, if nay, will be mentioned between '[]', like this :
# master     eacf32 [origin/master: ahead 2, behind 3] ...
git branch -vv
```